# Сохранятся ли SharedPreferences при переустановке приложения

Tags: android

Я реализовал банальную функцию "лайки" ("Мне нравится").
Сохранит ли программа факт нажатия на кнопку при переустановке приложения на новую версию с тем же именем пакета?

Comment: У меня сложилось впечатление, что обе части вашего вопроса состоят из одного и того же условия - настройки останутся прежними (второе приложение получит настройки первого). Наверное, вы хотели спросить, будут ли при переустановке приложения (фактически установка нового приложения с тем же пакаджнэйм - переустановка первого) сохранены настройки или они удалятся и переустановленное приложение будет с новыми настройками?

Comment: @pavlofff , возможно, я неправильно задал вопрос. Суть в том, что мне нужно знать, сохранит ли программа факт нажатия на кнопку при переустановке приложения на новую версию с тем же package name.

Comment: да, сохранит, естественно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если приложения будут иметь одинаковый package name, то оно будет перезаписано, но такие настройки, как Shared Preferences останутся (не удалятся), т.к. если бы они удалялись, то после каждого обновления приложения из маркеты у вас бы удалялся весь прогресс и, возможно, платный контент, а это было бы плохо для пользователя.

Что по поводу Shared Preferences, то это всего навсего XML файл, который хранится в папке с приложением, а сам класс уже парсит этот файл на наличие данных, и если во 2 приложении вы добавили новые поля для сохранения в SP, то это не значит, что файл будет перезаписан с новыми полями, по дефолту их там вообще не будет, только после 1 добавления они появятся.

Comment: Уточните вопрос по поводу у 2 приложения есть Shared Preferences, при запакаованном виде у приложения нету Shared Preferences, т.е. если у вас APK файл, то там ещё нету полей в Shared Preferences.

Comment: спасибо, мне все стало понятно. Дело в том, что я реализовал банальную функцию "лайки" ("Мне нравится"), пытаюсь понять, сохранятся ли настройки (в данном случае, нажимал ли пользователь на на кнопку или нет) при переустановке файла. Как я понял, да, сохранятся.